# Is there a way to write a custom ggplot theme function with non-standard arguments?

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2, themes

I am trying to write a custom ggplot theme, following, e.g. https://joeystanley.com/blog/custom-themes-in-ggplot2/

It's easy enough, but I would like to add the complication that some of my plots need only grid lines on the X axis, while others need it only on the Y axis (none need it on both).  I'd like to add an argument to the theme function to specify which is the draw axis, such that within the figure script, I can call `my_theme(gridline_axis = "x")` and have the gridlines draw only on the x axis.

However, I've been unable to figure out how to add a conditional argument within the theme() function.  I believe the challenge is getting the conditional statement to evaluate as an argument to theme--though I've tried toString(), eval(), and assign().

```
my_theme <- function(gridline_axis = "x") {
  
  draw_axis = ifelse(gridline_axis == "x", yes = "x", no = "y")
  blank_axis = ifelse(draw_axis == "x", yes = "y", no = "x")
  
  
  my_theme = theme_bw(base_size = 12) %+replace%
    
    theme(      
      #gridline settings -- user input of "x" produces major gridlines on the x axis and removes on Y axis
      paste("panel.grid.major.",toString(blank_axis),sep = "") = element_blank(),    
      paste("panel.grid.minor.",toString(blank_axis),sep = "") = element_blank(),
      paste("panel.grid.major.",toString(draw_axis),sep = "") = element_line(
        color = "gray",
        linewidth = 0.5,
        linetype = 1
      ),
      paste("panel.grid.minor.",toString(draw_axis),sep = "") = element_line(linetype = 1)
    )
  
}
```

returns:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"      #gridline settings -- user input of "x" produces major gridlines on the x axis and removes on Y axis
      toString(paste("panel.grid.major.",toString(blank_axis),sep = "")) ="
```

I've also tried building in an if statement within the primary call to theme()--this is unsuccessful as it overwrites anything called to theme() outside of the if statement.

I've also tried using theme_set() after the portion of the theme that I don't wish to change, and then theme_update() based on the if statement for the portion that I do wish to change.  This failed, though I'm not sure why.

I am trying to avoid duplicating the arguments that I don't wish to change on any plot by fully duplicating the %+replace% based on an if else statement.

EDITED to make clear that in addition to the variables that change between plots, there are some calls to 'theme()' that should remain the same in both plots.  I have not found a solution that allows for both.  For example:

```
my_theme <- function(gridline_axis = "x") {
  t <- theme_bw(base_size = 12)
  
  #settings that apply to all plots
  settings = list(
    
    #text settings
    plot.title = element_text(size = 15, vjust = 3),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 13),
    axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -2),
    axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 5.5),
    
    #plot settings
    plot.background = element_rect(colour = "black",
                                   linewidth = 1),
    plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "cm"),
    
    #panel settings
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    
    #test to make it obvious if this is working
    panel.border = element_rect(color = "red", linewidth = 2)
  )
  
  #settings that apply to some plots based on gridline_axis call
  draw_axis <- if (gridline_axis == "x") "x" else "y"
  blank_axis <- if (gridline_axis == "x") "y" else "x"
  
  panel_grid <- list(
    element_blank(), 
    element_blank(),
    element_line(
      color = "gray",
      linewidth = 0.5,
      linetype = 1
    ),
    element_line(linetype = 1)
  )
  
  names(panel_grid) <- c(
    paste0("panel.grid.", c("minor", "major"), ".", blank_axis),
    paste0("panel.grid.major.", draw_axis),
    paste0("panel.grid.minor.", draw_axis)
  )
  
  l = c(settings, panel_grid)
  
  t %+replace%
    do.call(theme, args = c(l))
}



p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point()

p +
  my_theme("x"
  )
```

[image: ggplot2 figure]

The same result is produced when I use `if` as in the provided solution by Stefan.  Thank you all for your help, I am learning a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a simple character string to dynamically create a function argument and assign a value to it (but see below for an option using `do.call`). Also, while I'm always trying to avoid duplicating code, for the present use case I would use an `if-else` like so:

```r
my_theme <- function(gridline_axis = "x") {
  t <- theme_bw(base_size = 12)

  grid_major <- element_line(
    color = "gray",
    linewidth = 0.5,
    linetype = 1
  )
  grid_minor <- element_line(linetype = 1)

  t <- t %+replace%
    if (gridline_axis == "x") {
      theme(
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = grid_major,
        panel.grid.minor.x = grid_minor
      )
    } else {
      theme(
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = grid_major,
        panel.grid.minor.y = grid_minor
      )
    }

  t
}

library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point()

p +
  my_theme()
```

[image]

```r
p +
  my_theme("y")
```

[image]

As a second approach here is an option using `do.call` which is probably more in line with what you are trying to achieve:

```r
my_theme <- function(gridline_axis = "x") {
  t <- theme_bw(base_size = 12)

  draw_axis <- if (gridline_axis == "x") "x" else "y"
  blank_axis <- if (gridline_axis == "x") "y" else "x"
  
  panel_grid <- list(
    element_blank(), 
    element_blank(),
    element_line(
      color = "gray",
      linewidth = 0.5,
      linetype = 1
    ),
    element_line(linetype = 1)
  )
  
  names(panel_grid) <- c(
    paste0("panel.grid.", c("minor", "major"), ".", blank_axis),
    paste0("panel.grid.major.", draw_axis),
    paste0("panel.grid.minor.", draw_axis)
  )
  
  t %+replace%
    do.call(theme, args = panel_grid)
}

p +
  my_theme()
```

[image]

```r
p +
  my_theme("y")
```

[image]

**EDIT** For the second approach (but it works the same for the first one) you can set the "general" parameters for your custom theme like so:

```r
my_theme <- function(gridline_axis = "x") {
  t <- theme_bw(base_size = 12)

  t <- t %+replace%
    theme(
      # text settings
      plot.title = element_text(size = 15, vjust = 3),
      axis.title = element_text(size = 13),
      axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -2),
      axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 5.5),

      # plot settings
      plot.background = element_rect(
        colour = "black",
        linewidth = 1
      ),
      plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "cm"),
      # panel settings
      panel.background = element_blank(),
      # test to make it obvious if this is working
      panel.border = element_rect(color = "red", linewidth = 2)
    )

  draw_axis <- if (gridline_axis == "x") "x" else "y"
  blank_axis <- if (gridline_axis == "x") "y" else "x"

  panel_grid <- list(
    element_blank(),
    element_blank(),
    element_line(
      color = "gray",
      linewidth = 0.5,
      linetype = 1
    ),
    element_line(linetype = 1)
  )

  names(panel_grid) <- c(
    paste0("panel.grid.", c("minor", "major"), ".", blank_axis),
    paste0("panel.grid.major.", draw_axis),
    paste0("panel.grid.minor.", draw_axis)
  )

  t %+replace%
    do.call(theme, args = panel_grid)
}

p +
  my_theme("y")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Stefan!  Can you explain further your statement that "The issue is that you can't use an expression on the left hand side of = "?  I see and use things like, names(panel_grid) = ... all the time, which is why I thought my approach would work, so I can't quite figure out what the definition of "expression" is here.

Comment: I appreciate both of your solutions, both work to solve the originally described problem.  I have edited my question to make clear that, in addition I would like to be able to edit other settings in 'theme()' that would apply to all plots.  I am struggling to apply either solution here to that scenario--see above.  Thank you again.

Comment: See my edit on how to deal with the more general case. And yes. You are right. My statement that we can't have "expression"s on the LHS of an assignment was definitely too sloppy. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a good reference on that. We can e.g. do `names(panel_grid)=....` as R provides a special `names<-` assignment operator (see `?names`). But you can't do `paste0("x", 1) <- 1` to create a variable `x1`. Similarly you can't do `list(paste0("x", 1) = 1)` to name a list element. That's why we need `assign` or `setNames` or the walrus operator `:=` in the tidyverse.

Comment: I see--it's a special assignment for `names()` that allows that left hand assignment--thanks.  For your edit, I appreciate the clarification, but it looks like your code produces the same error as mine, where adding the general settings overwrites both the gridline settings and the plot data, to display a figure that is completely blank (displaying "general" settings but not "specific" settings).  Am I missing something?

Comment: Add `fill = NA` to `panel.border`. This is actually mentioned in the docs: `panel.border: border around plotting area, drawn on top of plot so that it covers tick marks and grid lines. This should be used with fill = NA`

Comment: THANK YOU!  Can't believe how long I struggled with that.  I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the upcoming ggplot2 version you can use 'walrus injection' using `!!name := value`. However, I'd argue that Stefan's approach is more canonical.

```r
library(ggplot2)
packageVersion("ggplot2")
#> [1] '3.5.0'

my_theme <- function(gridline_axis = "x") {
  
  draw_axis = ifelse(gridline_axis == "x", yes = "x", no = "y")
  blank_axis = ifelse(draw_axis == "x", yes = "y", no = "x")
  
  
  my_theme = theme_bw(base_size = 12) %+replace%
    
    theme(      
      #gridline settings -- user input of "x" produces major gridlines on the x axis and removes on Y axis
      !!paste("panel.grid.major.",toString(blank_axis),sep = "") := element_blank(),    
      !!paste("panel.grid.minor.",toString(blank_axis),sep = "") := element_blank(),
      !!paste("panel.grid.major.",toString(draw_axis),sep = "")  := element_line(
        color = "gray",
        linewidth = 0.5,
        linetype = 1
      ),
      !!paste("panel.grid.minor.",toString(draw_axis),sep = "") := element_line(linetype = 1)
    )
  
}

p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point()

p + my_theme("x")
```

[image]

```r
p + my_theme("y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>